# How can I produce a graphql schema for federation with java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-spqr, graphql-spring-boot

My group is planning to use Apollo Gateway for federation. Therefore, we need to produce our schemas a little bit differently.

Can we produce something like this with using your amazing lib?

```
extend type User @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  reviews: [Review]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add some fields and directives to a type?

You can use `@GraphQLContext` to attach external methods as fields. Or even provide a custom `ResolverBuilder` that returns additional `Resolver`s (these later get mapped to fields).
To add directives, you can create annotations meta-annotated with `@GraphQLDirective` (see the tests for examples).
Lastly, you can of course provide a custom `TypeMapper` for `User` and fully take control of how that type gets mapped.

E.g. you can make an annotation like:

```
@GraphQLDirective(locations = OBJECT)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Key {
    public String[] fields;
}
```

If you then place this annotation on a type:

```
@Key(fields = "id")
public class User {
    @External //another custom annotation
    public @GraphQLId @GraphQLNonNull String getId() {...}
}
```

it will get mapped as:

```
type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID! @external
}
```

I presume you know about `@GraphQLContext`, but in short:

```
//Some service class registered with GraphQLSchemaBuilder
@GraphQLApi
public class UserService {

    @GraphQLQuery
    public List<Review> getReviews(@GraphQLContext User user) {
        return ...; //somehow get the review for this user
    }
}
```

Because of `@GraphQLContext`, the type `User` now has a `review: [Review]` field (even though the `User` class does not have that field).

Comment: Thanks! But its seems not work. Please see at https://github.com/safaksahin/graphqldemo